# can't find my files

Tags: home-directory

I am using Ubuntu 12.04 LTS and I reinstalled it for some reason. Earlier my `/home` was different from `/`. After reinstalling Ubuntu, I can't find my files(documents, downloads, music, etc) even when it is showing occupied space correctly, but the folders are empty. Help!

Here is my `/home`:

```
gurmeet@gurmeet:~$ ls -l /home 
total 20 
drwxr-xr-x 24 gurmeet gurmeet 4096 Sep 9 13:25 gurmeet 
drwx------ 59 root root 16384 Jul 29 02:34 lost+found
```

Comment: while reinstalling Ubuntu your files may have been deleted. what are the steps you took while reinstalling it? did you took any backup of your files?

Comment: no i didn't took any backup as I was sure that keeping the / and /home separate will not delete my files during installation. During installation I formatted the / partition and mounted the home on /home. You are saying that my files may have been deleted by it is still showing the occupied space correctly, that means my file are are not deleted.

Comment: Please run `ls -l /home` and add this information to your question.

Comment: The best way to add additional information to your question is by editing it, with the *edit* button. It is better visible that way, and comments are mainly for secondary, temporary purposes. Comments are removed under a variety of circumstances. Anything important to your question should be in the question itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should find you files inside `/home/lost+found` directory. However, I worry about their structure which may become lost. This happened because you have set new user's name the same as it was.

You shouldn't do this. Better practice is to make new user with different name then copy files from old user.

To open this directory, run inside terminal:

```
cd /home
sudo chown gurmeet:gurmeet lost+found
```

Comment: i tried to open the lost+found directory but it says "You do not have the permissions necessary to view the contents of "lost+found"."

Comment: Check the answer again. I added information about how to open this directory.

Comment: thanks a lot, I found my files and you were right the structure is gone but a least I have my data, thnks bless u. :)